# unwrite if statements with switch and case, php gilded rose

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

https://github.com/emilybache/GildedRose-Refactoring-Kata/tree/main/php

im doing the gilded rose refactoring kata for php right now. I have written some unittests and they all work with the standard GildedRose.php code. Now i wanted to refactory the 40 line of if statements to do the code easier to read, but somewhere a mistake has crept in and idk where and how.

my unittest are like (for each item):

```
public function testAgedBrieAtBeginning(): void          //  +1 quality till sell_in = 0 than +2 quality
{
    $items = [new Item('Aged Brie', 2, 0)];
    $gildedRose = new GildedRose($items);
    $gildedRose->updateQuality();
    $this->assertEquals($items[0]->sell_in, 1);
    $this->assertEquals($items[0]->quality, 1);
}

public function testAgedBrieWhenSellInZero(): void
{
    $items = [new Item('Aged Brie', 0, 2)];
    $gildedRose = new GildedRose($items);
    $gildedRose->updateQuality();
    $this->assertEquals($items[0]->sell_in, -1);
    $this->assertEquals($items[0]->quality, 4);
}

public function testAgedBrieDontIncreaseMaximum(): void       // stand at 50 quality
{
    $items = [new Item('Aged Brie', -28, 50)];
    $gildedRose = new GildedRose($items);
    $gildedRose->updateQuality();
    $this->assertEquals($items[0]->sell_in, -29);
    $this->assertEquals($items[0]->quality, 50);
}
```

and my GildedRose.php is:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace GildedRose;

final class GildedRose
{
/**
 * @var Item[]
 */
private $items;

public function __construct(array $items)
{
    $this->items = $items;

}

public function updateQuality(): void
{
    switch ($this->items) {
        case 'Normal':
            $this->tickNormal();
            return;
        case 'Aged Brie':
            $this->tickAgedBrie();
            return;
        case 'Sulfaras, Hand of Ragnaros':
            $this->tickSulfuras();
            return;
        case 'Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert':
            $this->tickBackstage();
            return;
    }

}

private function tickNormal(): void  // for Dexterity, Elixir & Conjured
{
    $this->sell_in--;

    if($this->quality == 0) {
        return;
    }

    $this->quality--;
    if ($this->sell_in <= 0) {
        $this->quality--;
    }
}
private function tickAgedBrie()
{
    $this->sell_in -= 1;

    if($this->quality >= 50) {
        return;
    }

    $this->quality += 1;
    if ($this->sell_in <= 0) {
        $this->quality += 1;
    }
}

private function tickSulfuras() : void
{

}

private function tickBackstage() : void
{
    $this->sell_in -= 1;

    if ($this->quality >= 50) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->sell_in < 0) {
        $this->quality = 0;
        return;
    }

    $this->quality += 1;
    if ($this->sell_in < 10) {
        $this->quality += 1;
    }
    if ($this->sell_in < 5) {
        $this->quality += 1;
    }
}

}
```

Firstly: The code was a full chaos. Look at the github repository /src/GildedRose.php. I have write some unittest to the original code to save the program. my unittest looks all similar to above. I test the changes of every items as they should be (https://github.com/emilybache/GildedRose-Refactor). After the unittests, i started to change the GildedRose.php to uncode the if-statements..

Comment: You'd better explain to us what's going wrong...we don't get points for guessing. Tell us a) what changes you made compared to the original version of the class (and show us the original, for comparison), b) what results you expected, and c) what results you actually got. Then we have a starting point, and aren't just speculating. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: For those of us who don't immediately know: [here's a short introduction to the Gilded Rose Kata](https://kata-log.rocks/gilded-rose-kata).

Comment: Thanks for the update, but any and all information relevant to your problem must be _within_ your question, not linked to on external URLs which could change or disappear (see the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, specifically point 1 in the list).

Comment: @ADyson i'll edit the question and write it as it should be later. forgive me guys :)